# Web GL. Slow render with texture change

Tags: web, optimization, emscripten, webgl2

I'm using empscripten. After several tests, I came to the conclusion that if I draw 500 identical textures, everything works fine. But if I draw 2 different textures 500 times, I get a big load on CPU. 14 against 60% on the osx. In windows, almost the same problem (6 vs 16%), only the difference is small. both textures have a size of 2x2 pixels.

Can I somehow optimize this?

Comment: How are you swapping the textures? Do you draw A 500 times, then B 500 times or do you draw A – B 500 times?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: A 500 times - all ok, but ABABAB(500 times) - big load on cpu.

Comment: We need to see code. What does "swap" mean? Are you uploading textures for every swap or just using 2 previously uploaded textures? What functions are you using to do the the swapping?